# Printing lines for which an element repeated in one field is associated with another element repeated in another field

Tags: bash, shell, awk

I have a tab delimited file:

```
scaffold_991    201     SYT3
scaffold_991    9396    SYT3
scaffold_991    11241   SYT3
scaffold_991    204     A
scaffold_991    939     A
scaffold_991    1141    A
scaffold_3006   610     TXNL4A
scaffold_3006   614     TXNL4A
scaffold_82     3098096 TXNL4A
scaffold_82     3100933 TXNL4A
scaffold_997    667     SPNS1
scaffold_997    1241    SPNS1
scaffold_997    2722    SPNS1
scaffold_997    3618    SPNS1
scaffold_997    9410    SPNS1
scaffold_997    18724   SPNS1
```

...

I need to print all lines for which the names in field 3 (SYT3,TXNL4A,SPNS1, ...) are not associated with the same element in field 1.

So that the output is:

```
scaffold_3006   610     TXNL4A
scaffold_3006   614     TXNL4A
scaffold_82     3098096 TXNL4A
scaffold_82     3100933 TXNL4A
```

Or, if it's easier, this should also work:

```
scaffold_991    201     SYT3
scaffold_991    9396    SYT3
scaffold_991    11241   SYT3
scaffold_991    204     A
scaffold_991    939     A
scaffold_991    1141    A
scaffold_997    667     SPNS1
scaffold_997    1241    SPNS1
scaffold_997    2722    SPNS1
scaffold_997    3618    SPNS1
scaffold_997    9410    SPNS1
scaffold_997    18724   SPNS1
```

in other words a same repeated element in column 3 have to be associated to repetitions of a same element in column 1.

I could't find any similar question and don't know enough to try on my own.

I also have a list of the unique elements in column 3 (SYT3,TXNL4A,SPNS1).

And I noticed that ordering the 1st column will split repetitions of a same elemnt in column 3 only if that element is acossiated with more than one scaffold, resulting in:

```
scaffold_82     3098096 TXNL4A
scaffold_82     3100933 TXNL4A
scaffold_991    201     SYT3
scaffold_991    9396    SYT3
scaffold_991    11241   SYT3
scaffold_991    204     A
scaffold_991    939     A
scaffold_991    1141    A
scaffold_997    667     SPNS1
scaffold_997    1241    SPNS1
scaffold_997    2722    SPNS1
scaffold_997    3618    SPNS1
scaffold_997    9410    SPNS1
scaffold_997    18724   SPNS1
scaffold_3006   610     TXNL4A
scaffold_3006   614     TXNL4A
```

...

I guess identifying instances where a given element in column 3 is repeated at least a second time in a different place in the file (are separated a by a different element) would be another way of thinking about this:

So that I could have the output:

```
scaffold_3006   610     TXNL4A
scaffold_3006   614     TXNL4A
```

and could then delete all lines containing `TXNL4A`.

Comment: Does the order of lines matter? What have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With GNU awk for true multi-dimensional arrays:

```
$ awk '
    { map[$3][$1] = map[$3][$1] $0 ORS }
    END {
        for (f3 in map) {
            if (length(map[f3]) > 1) {
                for (f1 in map[f3]) {
                    printf "%s", map[f3][f1]
                }
            }
        }
    }
' file
scaffold_82     3098096 TXNL4A
scaffold_82     3100933 TXNL4A
scaffold_3006   610     TXNL4A
scaffold_3006   614     TXNL4A
```

Comment: Man, that was fast! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem can be just reduced to finding those values in field3, for which the values in field1 are not the same. So for each value in field3, you need to check if values in field1 for that field3 are all the same, and if they aren't, you should print out all the lines with that field3.

Saving the input into `input.txt`, I can:

```
cut -f 3 input.txt | sort -u |                              # get all unique fields from column 3
while read -r field3; do                                    # for each field in column 3
    tmp=$(grep $'\t'"$field3"'$' input.txt)                 # I get only values for this column                                         
    if [ "$(<<<"$tmp" cut -f1 | uniq | wc -l)" -ne 1 ]; then  # if the values in the column1 are not unique
        <<<"$tmp" cat                                          # then print all the values of column 3
    fi
done
```

but I felt like reading the file multiple times in a loop is not good for a big file, so I've come up with this:

```
awk '{print > "'"$tmpd"'/"$3}' input.txt                        # split the file to multiple files depending on column3 value
find "$tmpd" -type f | while read -r f; do                      # do the job for each splitted file
    if [ "$(cut -f1 "$f" | sort -u | wc -l)" -ne 1 ]; then
        cat "$f"
    fi
done
```

If the order of values is precious, you need to first get all the values of column3 to print, and then use grep to print them:

```
grep "$(
    # this is the same as the first method, but it just prints values of column 3
    cut -f 3 input.txt | sort -u | while read -r field3; do
        tmp=$(grep $'\t'"$field3"'$' input.txt)
        if [ "$(<<<"$tmp" cut -f1 | uniq | wc -l)" -ne 1 ]; then
            printf "%s\n" "$field3"
        fi
    # then from values of column3 the grep filter argument is constructed to filter out only those values of the file
    done | sed 's/\(.*\)/\t\1$/' | sed -z 's/\n/\\|/g;s/\\|$//'
)" input.txt
```

Live version available at [tutorialspoints](http://tpcg.io/whPKNh).

Comment: The 1st options works great, just slow, as you warned :) For the second one: the awk part gives me an error awk: cmd. line:1: (FILENAME=starts_ends_annot.txt FNR=1) fatal: can't redirect to `/RHOH' (Permission denied).

Answer (score 1):

This might work (there's probably a better solution though):

```
awk '{a[$3][$1][$0]=1}END{for (i in a) if (length(a[i])>1) for (j in a[i]) for (k in a[i][j]) print k}' file
```

- `a[$3][$1][$0]=1}` create an index for the lines grouped by `$3` and `$1`
- `for (...) for (...) for (...)` prints all lines per group where there's more than one `$1` for a `$3`

Output:

```
scaffold_82     3100933 TXNL4A
scaffold_82     3098096 TXNL4A
scaffold_3006   614     TXNL4A
scaffold_3006   610     TXNL4A
```

Comment: You should mention it needs GNU awk for true multi-dimensional arrays.